# GEE error: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'NDWI' did not match any bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, sentinel-2, normalized-difference-water-index

I want to find the NDWI and NDCI of my study area from the Sentinel 2 image in google earth engine but i get a error that it did not match any bands.

How can I solve this problem?

my code here:

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60').clip(geometry);
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var IMG = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .mosaic();

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};


var IMG_water = function(IMG){
  //water mask
  var ndwi = IMG.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  return IMG.addBands(ndwi)
  .updateMask(ndwi.gt(0))
}

var IMG_NDCI = function(IMG){
  var ndci = IMG.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDCI');
  return IMG.addBands(ndci)
}


Map.centerObject(geometry, 9);
Map.addLayer(IMG, visualization, 'RGB');
Map.addLayer(IMG.select('NDWI'),{palette:['cyan']},"IMG_water")
Map.addLayer(IMG.select('NDCI'),visualization,"IMG_NDCI")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions, `IMG_water` and `IMG_NDCI`, that you never invoke. These are the ones adding the `NDWI` and `NDCI` bands. You either invoke them for each image in the collection, or on your final `IMG` composite.

You could try doing something like this:

```
var IMG = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30')
  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
  .map(function (image) {
    return maskS2clouds(
      IMG_water(
        IMG_NDCI(image)
      )
    )
  })
  .mosaic()
  
function IMG_water(IMG) {
  var ndwi = IMG.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')
  var water = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gt(0)).rename('WATER')
  return IMG
    .addBands(ndwi)
    .addBands(water)
}

function IMG_NDCI(IMG) {
  var ndci = IMG.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDCI')
  return IMG.addBands(ndci)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/795dfb435d1defa47b0939afebd96a8d

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("users/mpangihutan/Jakarta");

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-01-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(roi));

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Proses Sentinel - 2 
var image = dataset.median(); 
var clipped = image.clip(roi)

var ndwi = clipped.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename(['ndwi']);

var tss = clipped.expression(
       "(ndwi > 0.1) ? 2950 * pow(VNIR,1.357)"+
       ": 0",{
         'ndwi' : ndwi,
         'VNIR': image.select('B7')
}).rename('tss');
```

Where are the problem with B7?

Comment: You have posted a new Question in a space reserved for an Answer. Please ask new questions as a Question.